# RGBI to VGA converter

Tags: video, commodore-128, vga, old-hardware-adaptation

Is there an off the shelf converter / adapter from C128 RGBI to VGA that will work with modern-ish low voltage VGA?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Typically this requires using chained RGBI -> RGBA and RGBA -> VGA converters.

Answer (score 3):

RGBI to RGB only needs a couple of diodes and resistors, see e.g. [here](https://frank-buss.de/c128/vdc/index.html), and that will work with VGA-RGB. I am not aware off-the-shelf ones for that are available, OTOH they are not exactly difficult to make yourself.

I have no idea what @mnem means by "RGBA", usually this is an abbreviation for red-green-blue-alpha, and refers to how image data is stored on memory. There is no alpha channel when outputting this.

---

Here's the RGBI to VGA RGB conversion circuit:

[image: Schematic] 
<sup>Credit: Alex Hajnal based on circuit by [Frank Buß](https://frank-buss.de/c128/vdc/index.html)</sup>

The circuit above was based on the one shown below (from [this page](https://sites.google.com/site/h2obsession/CBM/C128/rgbi-to-vga)).  Personally<sup>1</sup> I'd go with the former circuit.

[image: Alternate schematic] 
<sup>Credit: Alex Hajnal based on circuit by [H2Obsession](https://sites.google.com/site/h2obsession/CBM/C128/rgbi-to-vga)</sup>

<sup>1</sup> Personally == @AlexHajnal's opinion

Comment: A as in analog, as opposed to digital RGBI. RGBA is a common abbreviation used in arcade circles, which is what a lot of the common inexpensive RGB to VGA adapters were originally made for.

Comment: Interesting, but for me analog RGB is still just RGB... and "digital" RGB is just RGB with two analog levels. RGBI is RGBI.